# Will university admissions google the academics who write my references?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, reference-request

I'm applying for masters. Will those reading my applications actually bother looking up the people that wrote my references?

I'm considering whether I should ask prestigious academics (who don't know me well) write my references vs not-so-prestigious ones (who know me). Obviously if they wont google the names, I should go with the latter.

Comment: Two false assumptions here: (1) the only way for the readers to know the prestige of the readers is by Googling them (2) the readers care about how prestigious your writers are.

Comment: A lukewarm reference from a famous name can actually be rather damaging.

Comment: @aparente001 why do you say that? My impression is that since that person has taken time to write a letter that should indicate the candidate it's a good prospect.

Comment: @user4050 Imagine you received the following reference letter from a famous person: "To whom it may concern: I met applicant X at university Y. She is a student. This is my recommendation letter for program Z. Salutations, Superstar W" Would you have a good impression of applicant X?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi frankly I don't know who could write such letter if they know at least a bit the applicant. In that case you described it's clear the professor didn't know anything about the candidate.